# Remove blank values from multi select ng-options

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a problem with `ng-options`. I can't get rid of the blank option in my `ng-options` with multi select.

I tried this [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29301366/unable-to-remove-blank-option-with-ng-options) but this works for single select. Is there any solution for multi select.

**HTML**

```
        <select ng-model="feed.config" ng-options="item.name for item in configs" multiple>
  <!--  <option value="" ng-if="false"></option> works only for single select --> 
        </select>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.feed = {};

$scope.configs = [{'name': null,'value': 'config1'},
                  {'name': 'Config 2', 'value': 'config2'},
                  {'name': 'Config 3','value': 'config3'}
                  ];
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UKySp/135/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure CSS solution is to use [**`:empty` pseudo-class**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) to hide the empty `options`:

```
select option:empty {
  display:none;
}
```

**`:empty` MDN reference:**

> The :empty CSS pseudo-class represents any element that has no children. Children can be either element nodes or text (including whitespace). Comments or processing instructions do not affect whether an element is considered empty or not.

Comment: Thanks it works but there is some typo will change it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter `configs` which exclude `null` data and then use it to bind `ngOption`

```
$scope.getConfigs = function () {
    return $scope.configs.filter(function (x) {
        return x.name != null;
    })
}
```

*HTML*

```
<select ng-model="feed.config" ng-options="item.name for item in getConfigs()" multiple>
</select>
```

```js
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp1', [])
MyApp.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.feed = {};

  $scope.configs = [{
    'name': null,
    'value': 'config1'
  }, {
    'name': 'Config 2',
    'value': 'config2'
  }, {
    'name': 'Config 3',
    'value': 'config3'
  }];

  $scope.getConfigs = function() {
    return $scope.configs.filter(function(x) {
      return x.name != null;
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp1">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">

    <select ng-model="feed.config" ng-options="item.name for item in getConfigs()" multiple>
    </select>

    <br> {{feed.config}}
  </div>

</div>
```

---

You can also create a `filter`

```js
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp1', []);

MyApp.filter('notNull', [function() {
  return function(object) {
    var array = object.filter(function(x) {
      return x.name != null;
    })
    return array;
  };
}])

MyApp.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.feed = {};

  $scope.configs = [{
    'name': null,
    'value': 'config1'
  }, {
    'name': 'Config 2',
    'value': 'config2'
  }, {
    'name': 'Config 3',
    'value': 'config3'
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp1">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">

    <select ng-model="feed.config" ng-options="item.name for item in configs | notNull " multiple>
    </select>

    <br> {{feed.config}}
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
Is there any similar solution like single select because I prefer any HTML and CSS side solution.

Answer (score 1):

check this it will work

```
   <select id="feed" ng-model="feed.config" >
<option ng-repeat="config in configs " value="{{config.name}} || Null" ng-bind="config.name"></option>
                                </select>
```

add css

```
select option:empty {
  display:none;
}
```

or without css
check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/16750/